# JAVASCRIPT options

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Let's say that I have created an image with three lines. And I want a client-user to be able to pick the color of each line. There are 5 possible values (say RED, BLUE, YELLOW, GREEN, VIOLET). I know how to do this for one line using JAVASCRIPT's "option" function. But what about all three? Must I write new code for each line, or can I reuse a single "option"? For test purposes, how do I print test output showing the color of each line -- something like line 1 = RED; line 2 = BLUE; line 3 = GREEN?

Comment: Could you please show your code for one line? Posting demo on http://jsfiddle.net would help too

Comment: I have a solution, but can't implement it without your code. Three buttons: one for each line of the image. When the user clicks a button, the corresponding line of the image will change to the currently selected option. (Same with the other two buttons). This can be done with a single function with a single parameter. As far as printing the colors, you should be able to do this by getting some attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're asking for.  Here's a working example of a color selector using an HTML select control:

HTML:

```
Select the color you would like: 
<select id="colorChooser">
    <option value="">Select a color</option>
    <option value="F00">Red</option>
    <option value="0F0">Green</option>
    <option value="00F">Blue</option>
</select><br>
<div id="selectedColor"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("colorChooser").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.value) {
        document.getElementById("selectedColor").style.backgroundColor = "#" + this.value;
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/68FWM/

Comment: Not sure if it's what the OP is asking, but it's good enough to show them how whatever they need to be done can be done

Comment: @JuanMendes - yeah, given the unclear question that's what I was trying to do.